# SURF descriptor implementation

Tags: opencv, implementation, surf, haar-wavelet, feature-descriptor

I want to generate **SURF descriptor** (a vector of length 64).
In the [original paper](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/eccv06.pdf), here it says:

> The region is split up regularly into smaller 4*4 square sub-regions. For each sub-region, we compute Haar wavelet responses at 5*5 regularly spaced sample points.

With **OpenCV** help, I can get keypoint and its relating region (by using `KeyPoint::size` and `angle`), but my questions are:
1. how to compute Haar wavelet responses?
2. what is *"at 5 x 5 regularly spaced sample points"* mean?

I've read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet#Discrete_wavelets) and [introduction](http://cva.stanford.edu/classes/ee482a/docs/lect01_sample.pdf) about Harr wavelet but still have no idea how to write the code.
I've known how to use the OpenCV `SurfDescriptorExtractor`, but I cannot use it because I need to enlarge or shrink the original region and get new descriptor.

Thanks for any hint about how to generate SURF descriptor.

Comment: could you be a bit more clear about why you can't use OpenCV's implementation?

Comment: @Hammer The descriptor `SurfDescriptorExtractor` generated are based on meaningful **rectangle region** of a SURF keypoint, however, I want to **enlarge or shrink the region** so that I can match those points that are not original matched by original descriptor

Comment: I see.  I'm sorry I don't understand the inner workings of SURF.  Have you considered upsampling or downsampling your image before sending it into OpenCV's implementation?  That would be fairly similar to enlarging or shrinking the region used.

Comment: The source code is in opencv/modules/nonfree/src/surf.cpp. I don't understand much of the code, but I see something related to Haar stuff here and descriptors. Maybe it helps and you can modify the code if you want. But I suggest you to try easier approachs.

Comment: @Hammer Thanks for your attention and helpful advice, I will take a try.